# Why can't web app in docker-compose, connect to another container in the same compose?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with at least 2 tomcat containers:
(Heads up, this is not a valid docker-compose, only a template)

```
version: "3"

services:
  restapidependencies:
     xxxxxx

  restapi:
    image: tomcat:8.0-jre8
    depends_on:
      - restapidependencies
    ports:
      - "8888:80"

    command: catalina.sh run

  web:
    image: tomcat:8.0-jre8
    depends_on:
      - coreservices
    ports:
      - "7777:80"

    command: catalina.sh run
```

One is a RESTful api and the other is a web app built on javascript (angularJS). There are an X numbers of other services that `restapi` depends on, (database, redis, etc). The rest api connects successfully to its dependencies using the name of the service defined in docker-compose.yaml, however, the application inside the `web` service cannot connect to the `restapi` service. That said, when I `docker exec` into the `web` container, I can successfully make request to the `restapi` using `curl`.

Is there a know scenario where a javascript application wouldn't be able to connect to a docker container in the same docker-compose.

PS: I did not develop the app running `web` so I have limited knowledge of anything special it may be doing, my front end developer gave me an explanation around the lines: "The web app is running inside the browser", which makes sense. 
Some thoughts: Does that means web apps don't have access to localhost either? Even if that is the case, docker compose creates a network of containers so no localhost is shared in the same app, technically `web` is calling a completely different ip, not localhost.

Answer (score 2):

*i docker exec into the web container, I can successfully make request to the restapi using curl*

Then your restapi **is** accessible from your web container. So it looks like a wrong configuration.

- Is there any log message?
- How does the app tries to bring up the connection?
- Maybe you forgot to define any environment variables for your webapp?
- Maybe your rest api doesn't exposes any port?

Try to get a log output that tells you why the connection fails.

Comment: The front end is making a GET request to this url: `http://restapi/myversion/public/logo`
The response is empty and the console shows the error:
`http://restapi/myversion/public/logo net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Looks ok to me, but I'd recommend to use `container_name:`, otherwise your service names get prefixed. I see your `restapi` is publishing to localhost on port 8888. Can you curl on your local machine to `localhost:8888/myversion/public/logo` ?

Comment: Requesting from my computer to `localhost:8888/myversion/public/logo` works.

Comment: The `restapi` is only accessible from outside of docker by using `http://localhost:8888`. When open the browser on my computer, it doesn't know who `http://restapi` is since it doesn't know about this docker network. This leads to the conclusion that web apps inside of docker containers cannot access other services in their docker-compose by using their docker-compose name's, but rather they need to act as if the other services where in a different network and call them by their `protocol://ip:port`, in this case, I would have to use `http://localhost:8888`.

Comment: Didn't you say, you can `docker exec` into your web container and successfully curl your restapi container? Of course, your local machine doesn't know about the hostname `restapi`, but all your services within the same compose file should know about it. I'm not sure, but maybe you could try to NOT forward restapis port 80 to localhosts 8888? So just `expose: - 80` instead of the `ports: - 8888:80` command?

Comment: Sadly, I have no chance at the moment to try by myself, but I'm also not sure about if the **service name** actually acts like the hostname when no container_name is specified. But I know for sure, **if you define a `container_name`, THIS will act as the hostname of your service.**

Comment: "if you define a container_name, THIS will act as the hostname of your service" 
Agreed, but only inside of that compose's network. I did try only exposing the port, but that didn't yield any results. 
I indeed am able to ping `restapi` from `web`. I also thought, just like you, that the application would also be able to access it, but considering that my Browser client is the one that statically runs the web app, then that connection won't work because this Browser is run on my computer, not inside of the compose's network.

Comment: I believe it might have worked if the web application was connecting with a non static method instead of pure javascript that runs only in the browser.

Comment: Two immediate solutions for my problem: 
1* add the hostname that the web app is trying to connect to, in the `/etc/hosts` folder.
2* Make the web app derive the current server public ip address and connect to that IP:8888
I like option 2 more.

Comment: @erielmarimon - I am in the same position as you are. Have you figured out how to "make the web app derive the current server public ip address" through docker/docker-compose itself, instead of hard-coding the service URL into the web app's JavaScript?